OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) in Conda Environment Jupiter Notebook
OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) in Conda Environment Jupiter Notebook
Got below error while running sql query in Jupiter notebook using condo environment
can anyone help to solve this error if you face previously.
error got on : macOS Ventura 13.4
Python version 3.11
Anaconda3-2024.02-1-MacOSX-arm64.pkg
Jupiter Notebook Version: 7.0.8
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:145, in Connection.__init__(self, engine, connection, _has_events, _allow_revalidate, _allow_autobegin)
    144 try:
--> 145     self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
    146 except dialect.loaded_dbapi.Error as err:
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:3293, in Engine.raw_connection(self)
   3272 """Return a "raw" DBAPI connection from the connection pool.
   3273 
   3274 The returned object is a proxied version of the DBAPI
   (...)
   3291 
   3292 """
-> 3293 return self.pool.connect()
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:452, in Pool.connect(self)
    445 """Return a DBAPI connection from the pool.
    446 
    447 The connection is instrumented such that when its
   (...)
    450 
    451 """
--> 452 return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:1269, in _ConnectionFairy._checkout(cls, pool, threadconns, fairy)
   1268 if not fairy:
-> 1269     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
   1271     if threadconns is not None:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:716, in _ConnectionRecord.checkout(cls, pool)
    715 else:
--> 716     rec = pool._do_get()
    718 try:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py:169, in QueuePool._do_get(self)
    168 except:
--> 169     with util.safe_reraise():
    170         self._dec_overflow()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:146, in safe_reraise.__exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
    145     self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
--> 146     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
    147 else:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py:167, in QueuePool._do_get(self)
    166 try:
--> 167     return self._create_connection()
    168 except:
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:393, in Pool._create_connection(self)
    391 """Called by subclasses to create a new ConnectionRecord."""
--> 393 return _ConnectionRecord(self)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:678, in _ConnectionRecord.__init__(self, pool, connect)
    677 if connect:
--> 678     self.__connect()
    679 self.finalize_callback = deque()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:902, in _ConnectionRecord.__connect(self)
    901 except BaseException as e:
--> 902     with util.safe_reraise():
    903         pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:146, in safe_reraise.__exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
    145     self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
--> 146     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
    147 else:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:898, in _ConnectionRecord.__connect(self)
    897 self.starttime = time.time()
--> 898 self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
    899 pool.logger.debug("Created new connection %r", connection)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py:645, in create_engine.<locals>.connect(connection_record)
    643             return connection
--> 645 return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:616, in DefaultDialect.connect(self, *cargs, **cparams)
    614 def connect(self, *cargs, **cparams):
    615     # inherits the docstring from interfaces.Dialect.connect
--> 616     return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py:130, in Connect(*args, **kwargs)
    128 from MySQLdb.connections import Connection
--> 130 return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py:185, in Connection.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    183 autocommit = kwargs2.pop("autocommit", False)
--> 185 super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
    186 self.cursorclass = cursorclass

OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 0x0002): tried: '/opt/anaconda3/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/anaconda3/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so' (no such file)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM vg_threat', engine)
      2 df.info(verbose=True)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:485, in read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize, dtype, dtype_backend)
    482     dtype_backend = "numpy"  # type: ignore[assignment]
    483 assert dtype_backend is not lib.no_default
--> 485 with pandasSQL_builder(con) as pandas_sql:
    486     return pandas_sql.read_query(
    487         sql,
    488         index_col=index_col,
   (...)
    494         dtype_backend=dtype_backend,
    495     )

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:851, in pandasSQL_builder(con, schema, need_transaction)
    848     raise ImportError("Using URI string without sqlalchemy installed.")
    850 if sqlalchemy is not None and isinstance(con, (str, sqlalchemy.engine.Connectable)):
--> 851     return SQLDatabase(con, schema, need_transaction)
    853 warnings.warn(
    854     "pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or "
    855     "database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 "
   (...)
    858     stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    859 )
    860 return SQLiteDatabase(con)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:1576, in SQLDatabase.__init__(self, con, schema, need_transaction)
   1574     self.exit_stack.callback(con.dispose)
   1575 if isinstance(con, Engine):
-> 1576     con = self.exit_stack.enter_context(con.connect())
   1577 if need_transaction and not con.in_transaction():
   1578     self.exit_stack.enter_context(con.begin())

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:3269, in Engine.connect(self)
   3246 def connect(self) -> Connection:
   3247     """Return a new :class:`_engine.Connection` object.
   3248 
   3249     The :class:`_engine.Connection` acts as a Python context manager, so
   (...)
   3266 
   3267     """
-> 3269     return self._connection_cls(self)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:147, in Connection.__init__(self, engine, connection, _has_events, _allow_revalidate, _allow_autobegin)
    145         self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
    146     except dialect.loaded_dbapi.Error as err:
--> 147         Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
    148             err, dialect, engine
    149         )
    150         raise
    151 else:
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:2431, in Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(cls, e, dialect, engine, is_disconnect, invalidate_pool_on_disconnect, is_pre_ping)
   2429 elif should_wrap:
   2430     assert sqlalchemy_exception is not None
-> 2431     raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
   2432 else:
   2433     assert exc_info[1] is not None

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:145, in Connection.__init__(self, engine, connection, _has_events, _allow_revalidate, _allow_autobegin)
    143 if connection is None:
    144     try:
--> 145         self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
    146     except dialect.loaded_dbapi.Error as err:
    147         Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
    148             err, dialect, engine
    149         )

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:3293, in Engine.raw_connection(self)
   3271 def raw_connection(self) -> PoolProxiedConnection:
   3272     """Return a "raw" DBAPI connection from the connection pool.
   3273 
   3274     The returned object is a proxied version of the DBAPI
   (...)
   3291 
   3292     """
-> 3293     return self.pool.connect()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:452, in Pool.connect(self)
    444 def connect(self) -> PoolProxiedConnection:
    445     """Return a DBAPI connection from the pool.
    446 
    447     The connection is instrumented such that when its
   (...)
    450 
    451     """
--> 452     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:1269, in _ConnectionFairy._checkout(cls, pool, threadconns, fairy)
   1261 @classmethod
   1262 def _checkout(
   1263     cls,
   (...)
   1266     fairy: Optional[_ConnectionFairy] = None,
   1267 ) -> _ConnectionFairy:
   1268     if not fairy:
-> 1269         fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
   1271         if threadconns is not None:
   1272             threadconns.current = weakref.ref(fairy)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:716, in _ConnectionRecord.checkout(cls, pool)
    714     rec = cast(_ConnectionRecord, pool._do_get())
    715 else:
--> 716     rec = pool._do_get()
    718 try:
    719     dbapi_connection = rec.get_connection()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py:169, in QueuePool._do_get(self)
    167     return self._create_connection()
    168 except:
--> 169     with util.safe_reraise():
    170         self._dec_overflow()
    171     raise

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:146, in safe_reraise.__exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
    144     assert exc_value is not None
    145     self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
--> 146     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
    147 else:
    148     self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py:167, in QueuePool._do_get(self)
    165 if self._inc_overflow():
    166     try:
--> 167         return self._create_connection()
    168     except:
    169         with util.safe_reraise():

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:393, in Pool._create_connection(self)
    390 def _create_connection(self) -> ConnectionPoolEntry:
    391     """Called by subclasses to create a new ConnectionRecord."""
--> 393     return _ConnectionRecord(self)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:678, in _ConnectionRecord.__init__(self, pool, connect)
    676 self.__pool = pool
    677 if connect:
--> 678     self.__connect()
    679 self.finalize_callback = deque()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:902, in _ConnectionRecord.__connect(self)
    900     self.fresh = True
    901 except BaseException as e:
--> 902     with util.safe_reraise():
    903         pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
    904 else:
    905     # in SQLAlchemy 1.4 the first_connect event is not used by
    906     # the engine, so this will usually not be set

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:146, in safe_reraise.__exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
    144     assert exc_value is not None
    145     self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
--> 146     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
    147 else:
    148     self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:898, in _ConnectionRecord.__connect(self)
    896 try:
    897     self.starttime = time.time()
--> 898     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
    899     pool.logger.debug("Created new connection %r", connection)
    900     self.fresh = True
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py:645, in create_engine.<locals>.connect(connection_record)
    642         if connection is not None:
    643             return connection
--> 645 return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:616, in DefaultDialect.connect(self, *cargs, **cparams)
    614 def connect(self, *cargs, **cparams):
    615     # inherits the docstring from interfaces.Dialect.connect
--> 616     return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py:130, in Connect(*args, **kwargs)
    127 """Factory function for connections.Connection."""
    128 from MySQLdb.connections import Connection
--> 130 return Connection(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py:185, in Connection.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    182 # PEP-249 requires autocommit to be initially off
    183 autocommit = kwargs2.pop("autocommit", False)
--> 185 super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
    186 self.cursorclass = cursorclass
    187 self.encoders = {k: v for k, v in conv.items() if type(k) is not int}

OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 0x0002): tried: '/opt/anaconda3/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/anaconda3/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so' (no such file), '/opt/anaconda3/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so' (no such file)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)


can you include the output of conda list in your question?
